# Using Porto theme 3.6.3 in Shopify how can I turn off add to cart on specific products?

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, cart, shopping-cart

In Shopify I need to control whether certain products are able to display add to cart.

In the past I have tagged the product as "hide cart" and switched theme template to a version without the button.

How could I do this using the Porto theme?

Does it have a built in method of doing this or do I need to manipulate the theme partials / templates?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I can think of is to add a tag to all the products that you want to hide the **add to cart** button from, for example `hide-add-to-cart`.

Then find the code that renders the button and wrap it in an `unless` statement:

```
{% unless product.tags contains 'hide-add-to-cart' %}
  <button>Add to cart</button>
{% endunless %}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have a built-in method of doing this or do I need to manipulate the theme partials/templates?

**No**, there is no way to do it, rather than modify the existing code or add a new template and assign the template to a particular product like your previous theme.

So basically there are 2 ways to achieve it:

1. as @Karim Tarek said you need to tag those products and then check the particular tag into snippets where the **Add to cart** formed and disable it or hide it.
2. you need to create a template where you simply copy the code from the default product template and comment the code is for **Add to cart** and choose this template for those products on which you don't want to show the Add to cart button.

Code samples:
1.

```
{% unless product.tags contains 'you tag to hide product' %}
  you HTML code that formed the Add to cart button
{% endunless %}
```

2. 

[image]
[image]